# A fillable table in Google Forms that records data in a specific Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a table with editable cells in a google form that lets people enter their recorded measurements. Then compile that information into a Google Sheet by specified columns.

I have tried the Awesome table but I cannot seem to get the script to work.

Broken Down, I need the Script to be able to:

- import a table into google forms
- edit the number of columns and rows
- allow multiple people to record their measurements individually
- Compile the recorded data into a sheet by column.

This may be a simple question that I am overthinking. But I am trying to avoid multiple questions on the same form, and think a table would be way easier.

Comment: It's not possible since there is no table item in [FormApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form). How about sending a Spreadsheet with a table to the users, and adding a button so they can submit the data to another Sheet?

Comment: I would totally work.

Answer (score 1):

As talked in the comments, since there is no table item in [FormApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form), this solution consists in sending a Sheet with a predefined table for users to fill. They will press a button and send the data to a master sheet.

**CODE**

```
function sendData() {           

  //Gets the sheet is being edited
  var sprsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = sprsheet.getActiveSheet();

  //Gets the data introduced by the user
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:L2");
  var values = range.getValues();

  //Gets the target sheet
  var mainsprsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("main sheet id");
  var targetSheet = mainsprsheet.getActiveSheet();

  //Adds a new row to the target sheet with the collected data
  targetSheet.appendRow(values);

  //Clear the cells (optional)
  range.clearContent();
}
```

**BUTTON**

To create the "submit" button to run the function above:

1. Go to Insert > Drawing
2. Design your own button
3. Save and close
4. Click on the button and then on the 3 dots at the right-top.
5. Click on "Assign script" and write `sendData`

You can place the button anywhere and resize it.

**NOTES**

- You might want to send copies of this sheet to the different users to avoid sharing of sensitive data.

**REFERENCES**

- [Range Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- Method [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#getvalues)
- Method [appendRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)